# Count something based on another column

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I can't find a way to count something in a table. In the example below, I would like to know how many fruits are > 2000kg (so 3 here).

I'm able to count for instance how many apple are > 2000kg, but I can't find how to deal with the full column and the empty cells.

Anyone can help?

```
Fruit      Vegetable    Kg
apple                   2100
pear                    100
orange                  200
           salad        3000
apple                   4000
orange                  5000
           carot        5990
pear                    500
```

Answer (score 2):

Use COUNTIFS():

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<>",C:C,">2000")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I don't understand the logic behind this. What exactly A:A; "<>" stands for? A:A is different of empty?

Comment: @GuillaumeH. it will only count those that are not empty strings in column A and where column C is greater than 2000.  the `"<>"` is literally saying not an empty string,  It can also be done `"<>" & ""` if that helps the understanding.